# Why Geopandas dissolve failed?

Tags: error, dissolve, geopandas

After polygonization of a raster, I would like to dissolve all polygons with same value.

So I tried to use :

```
gdf.dissolve(by='column')
gdf.dissolve(by='column', aggfunc='first')
gdf.dissolve('column')
```

But every time it returns same error :

> Assertion failed: (!static_cast("should never be reached")),
>   function itemsTree, file AbstractSTRtree.cpp, line 373. Abort trap: 6

My geodataframe have only 2 fields, geometry and raster_val

What is wrong?

Comment: Are you using gdal? https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/375

Comment: Yes effectively. I just tried to import geopandas before gdal and now a new error with just a little message `Segmentation fault: 11`